# Como alinhar o botão a dois inputs?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap, input

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Button Tags</h2>


  <form>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>


</div>
```

Forma como aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero o botão na mesma linha dos inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```css
.btn-enviar {
  margin-top: 9.5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Button Tags</h2>


  <form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-enviar">Send invitation</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


</div>
```

Expande o trecho de código

Comment: Eu só não adicionaria o margin em uma classe default, pois pode implicar na usabilidade em outras páginas. sugiro que crie uma outra classe para o margin-top

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo que dê uma lida no [Bootstrap grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) caso vá usar bootstrap.

Para alinhar seu botão abaixo (presumi que era abaixo que você queria, baseado no trecho de código que você deu), simplesmente adicionei a classe `form-control` no botão, e coloquei dentro de uma div com a classe `col-md-12`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Button Tags</h2>

<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><label       for="exampleInputName2">Name</label></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
            
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
            </span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
            
            <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Send invitation</button>
   </span>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>



</div>
```

Comment: da uma olhada no meu edit

Comment: @CalebeMachado vê se o meu edit é o que você queria

Comment: O ideal mesmo é da forma como mostro na imagem e o botão alinha aos inputs, vou aplicar esse form em um cadastro gigantesco de um erp.

Comment: @CalebeMachado Não te entendi. Eu coloquei na vertical, você disse pra mudar pra horizontal, igual tá na imagem, foi o que eu fiz, aí você aceitou a resposta do cara que fez o que eu tinha feito, mas tudo bem